# How to send any image file to a particular whatsapp contact through Custom Url Scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I got success in sending text to a particular WhatsApp contact using this code

```
private void openWhatsApp(String mobileNumber) {
    String text = "Hi";
    if(whatsappInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp")){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="+text+ "&phone="+mobileNumber));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Now I want to share imageFile along with the text. I got the file path but don't know how to put in that browserIntent. Please Help.

Comment: Did you achieve it brother ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer but incase any one wondering.
**Here is how you can use intent to share image file on Whatsapp**

```
    Intent share = new Intent();
    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = file; // here path to your image file

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    Log.e("media", String.valueOf(uri));
    share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(share);
```

PS NOTE: You cannot send image with text as I tried some but fail to achieve it but you can share image file only from above code